# An attribute in Entity results nil value in swift4

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a swift project with 3 entities in my xcdatamodeld: Access, CustomerInfo and User. I am trying to save the dateEndSubscription separately in the User. When I am trying to save the dateEndSubscription, it gives null value.

What is mistake in my code ?
My code is here:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import CoreData

class DataManager: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = DataManager()

func loadUser() -> User? {
    let users = loadEntity(name: Entity.User)
    if let user = users.first as? User {
        return user
    }
    return nil
}
//this for deleteuser
func deleteUser() {
    deleteEntity(entityName: Entity.User)
}

func saveUser(userInfo:JSON, handler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    deleteEntity(entityName: Entity.User)
    deleteEntity(entityName: Entity.Access)

    let entity = createEntity(withName:Entity.User)

    let info = userInfo.dictionaryValue
    let userId = (info[API.Id]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let dateEnd = (info[API.DateEnd]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
      // this produces with no value.
    let type = (info[API.UserType]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    let cyberAccount = (info[API.CyberAccount]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let product = (info[API.Product]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    let user = User(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    user.setValue(userId, forKey:API.Id)
    user.setValue(dateEnd, forKey: API.DateEnd)
    user.setValue(type, forKey:API.UserType)
    user.setValue(cyberAccount, forKey:API.CyberAccount)
    user.setValue(product, forKey:API.Product)

    let accessInfo = info[API.Access]!
    saveUserAccess(accessInfo: accessInfo)


    handler(save)
}
 //this for saving useraccess
func saveUserAccess(accessInfo:JSON) -> Void {
    let entity = createEntity(withName:Entity.Access)

    let info = accessInfo.dictionaryValue

    let photo = (info[API.Photo]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let chat = (info[API.Chat]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let product = (info[API.Product]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let profile = (info[API.Profile]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let curve = (info[API.Curve]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let weeks = (info[API.Weeks]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let recipe = (info[API.Recipe]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let shopping = (info[API.Shopping]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let rdv = (info[API.RDV]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    let userAccess = User(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    userAccess.setValue(photo, forKey:API.Photo)
    userAccess.setValue(chat, forKey:API.Chat)
    userAccess.setValue(product, forKey:API.Product)
    userAccess.setValue(profile, forKey:API.Profile)
    userAccess.setValue(curve, forKey:API.Curve)
    userAccess.setValue(weeks, forKey:API.Weeks)
    userAccess.setValue(recipe, forKey:API.Recipe)
    userAccess.setValue(shopping, forKey:API.Shopping)
    userAccess.setValue(rdv, forKey:API.RDV)
}
// This for saving customer info
func saveCustomerInformation(customerInfo: JSON, handler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let entity = createEntity(withName:Entity.CustomerInfo)

    let info = customerInfo.dictionaryValue

    let userId = (info[API.Id]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let type = (info[API.UserType]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let cyberAccount = (info[API.CyberAccount]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let product = (info[API.Product]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let dateEnd = (info[API.DateEnd]?.stringValue ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

  print("Butwal",dateEnd)

    let user = User(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    user.setValue(userId, forKey:API.Id)
    user.setValue(type, forKey:API.UserType)
    user.setValue(cyberAccount, forKey:API.CyberAccount)
    user.setValue(product, forKey:API.Product)
    user.setValue(dateEnd, forKey: API.DateEnd)
  print("Butwal1",dateEnd)

    let accessInfo = info[API.Access]!
    saveUserAccess(accessInfo: accessInfo)


    handler(save)
}

//MARK: Load and Save Objects for Key
func loadObject(forKey key:String) -> Any? {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    guard let object = userDefaults.object(forKey: key) else {
        return nil
    }

    return object as AnyObject
}

func saveObject(object:Any, forKey key:String) {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(object, forKey: key)
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}

private func loadEntity(name : String) -> [Any] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:name)
    let objects = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return objects
}

// MARK: Delete Entities
private func deleteEntity(entityName name:String) {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: name)
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)
    deleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs

    do {
        let result = try context.execute(deleteRequest) as? NSBatchDeleteResult
        guard let objectIDs = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] else { return }
        let changes = [NSUpdatedObjectsKey: objectIDs]
        NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes, into: [context])
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Failed to execute request: \(error)")
    }
}

private func createEntity(withName name:String) -> NSEntityDescription {
    return NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: name, in: context)!
}

private var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.context
}



private var save: Bool {
    return CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.saveContext(rollBackOnError: true)
}
}

struct API {
       static let DateEnd      = "dateEndSubscription"
         }

Here are the screenshots for the data model of coredata. I have included all 3 entities with their relationships and inverse.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need the value of dateEndSubscription from the server. But while I am parsing, it returns no value. I have also created dateEndSubscription attributes in User entity.

Comment: Joakim Danielson @ No, it doesn't show any error.

Comment: **What** “gives a null value”? What problem are you having?

Comment: I can’t see dateEndSubscription anywhere in your code, just as an attribute of User. Is it some mismatch with your API.DateEnd? Without more info, like how you determine the value is nil and sight of where the attribute dateEndSubscription is referenced it’ll be tough to help.

Comment: So the previous question has been answered?

Comment: Magnas @ I have written there struct API below in the code section.